# correct certificate store for a x509 pfx file

Tags: windows, ssl, certificate, iis-7.5, x509

I'm installing a self signed x509 certificate on a windows 2008 machine,

The main purpose of this certificate is to secure comunication between a website and some customers.

I've generated the the public key, private key and the pfx file, but when I try to install the PFX file the wizard ask me in wich store I want to put the certificate

can someone please tell me the correct store I have to use?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use Trusted Root Certification Authorities.
See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733813.aspx